# Issue in calculating frame drop rate

Tags: python, python-2.7, frame-rate

I am struggling to understand and need confirmation in this regard. I am calculating the percentage of frame drop rate per second which is affected by the processing capability of the device and network for distributed deep neural network application consisting of client and server.

I have the following pseudocode for calculating frame drop rate of my application.

Client

```
 TIME_DELTA=1
 before_sent = frame_requests
 time.sleep(TIME_DELTA)
 after_sent = frame_requests
 client-side=(after_sent - before_sent) / TIME_DELTA
```

Server

```
 TIME_DELTA=1
 before_received = frame_requests
 time.sleep(TIME_DELTA)
 after_received = frame_requests
 server-side=(after_received - before_received) / TIME_DELTA
```

Frame drop rate

```
 Frame-drop-rate=client-side - serverside
```

I need to confirm is this the right way to calculate it. Your suggestions and thoughts are highly appreciated to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Why would you use Python-2.7?

Comment: You cant have hyphens in variable-names.

Comment: Thanks, @wuerfelfreak its a pseudocode, not complete code written in more code style

Comment: Thanks,@zabop, it was by mistake added this tag, next will make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frame_drop_rate=client_side - serverside` would be the **number** of Frames dropped per second.

`Frame_drop_rate= 1 - (client_side / serverside)` would be the *rate* of Frames dropped **each** second.

The term "rate per second" refers to the change in dropped frames over time. So wheter it is getting worse or better but not how good or bad it is.

Also: No hyphens in variable names. And check your variable spelling `serverside`/`server-side`